# ValueError: too many values to unpack when passing array to include method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to pass an array to include method, and it returns an error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`
What's wrong?

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from apps.management.urls import router as management_router


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('', include([
        path('management/', management_router.urls)
    ])),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the error is in this line:

```
path('', include([
    path('management/', management_router.urls)  <---
])),
```

You should change it to:

```
path('management/', include(management_router.urls, namespace="management")),
```

Comment: A list is not a problem. Check docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/

Comment: List is not the problem(sorry I mis-marked the line), but the problem is with router, you need to pass the router inside `include()` function. More info: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/